# how to change pixels in Krita

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to write python script for Krita that will inverte colors in current layer.
I'm not using existing filter so I can use it as Boilerplate for writing other filters.

```
from krita import *;
width= Krita.instance().activeDocument().width();
height= Krita.instance().activeDocument().height();

l= Krita.instance().activeDocument().activeNode(); # get current layer
data= l.pixelData(0,0,width,height); # get pixels as QByteArray

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        for c in range(3):
            data[4*(y*width+x) + c] = 0xff - data[4*(y*width+x) + c];

l.setPixelData( data, 0, 0, width, height ); # copy back to image
Krita.instance().activeDocument().refreshProjection(); # refresh
```

I'm getting error
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\xff'`

If I instead try to just set one channel to 0xFF

```
data[4*(y*width+x) + c] = 0xff;
```

I'm getting error
`TypeError: 'QByteArray' object does not support item assignment`

So how can I change values of pixels ?

Comment: I managed to change every pixel by doing it like this:
`i= 4*(y*width+x) + c;
data= data[:i] + bytes([(0xff - int.from_bytes( data.at(i), 'big' ))]) + data[(i+1):];`
But with it performance is disaster.
Not even mentioning the syntax.